# How to add 'back button' in Yahoo login page in ios

Tags: ios

[image]I am integrating Yahoo into my app for login purpose,Everything is working fine.But now i want to add an 'Back' Button at the Yahoo's login page to allow the user to get back to my app if he don't wants to login via Yahoo.

Comment: share your code you have tried.

Comment: i have followed the steps mentioned in https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc

Comment: please share screenshots its easy to understand

Comment: Ya Now i have updated my question with Screenshot,in that i need to add a BACK button to go back to my app

Comment: In this demo Yahoo opened in webview same controller that's why you dont show navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

search `YahooSession.m` on your project
now find `sendUserToAuthorization` in YahooSession.m and replace UIWebView

// Use UIWebView

```
self.rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
        self.authorizationWebView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, self.rootViewController.view.frame.size.width, self.rootViewController.view.frame.size.height)];
        [self.authorizationWebView setDelegate:self];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.authorizationUrl];
        [self.authorizationWebView loadRequest:request];
        [self.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.authorizationWebView];
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i got the temporary solution by creating button in **getResponseDelay** method (under YahooSession.m) and assigning a action to it,as below

```
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:@"< Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 15, 60, 10);
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
       [ button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.authorizationWebView addSubview:button];
```

-(void)method
{
   [self.authorizationWebView removeFromSuperview];

}